# Stomp WebSocket subscribe to two different topics

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I have one websocket server and one websocket client both in Java. The websocket server has this:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(final HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
}
```

And in the Java WebSocket client I have the following in my StompSessionHandler.afterConnected:

```
session.subscribe("/topic/greetings", stompFrameHandler)
```

Then, I am able to communicate between the two by, the client sending a message to the server path "hello" and then since the client is subscribed to "topic/greetings", I am also to handle the response with my stompFrameHandler.

But I am wondering if it is possible for a client to subscribe to two different "channels", so something like this in StompSessionHandler.afterConnected:

```
session.subscribe("/topic/greetings", greetingsFrameHandler)
session.subscribe("/topic/farewell", farewellFrameHandler)
```

Because I tried and I can only receive events from topic/greetings, but not for topic/farewell. I do not know if this is important, but to trigger a farewell event I make a rest call to the websocket server:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/sendFarewellEvent", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
@SendTo("/topic/farewell")
public Farewell farewell(@RequestBody final Farewell farewell) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return farewell;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am wondering if it is possible for a client to subscribe to two different "channels"

Yes, that works.

> to trigger a farewell event I make a rest call to the websocket server

Just combining `@PostMapping` with `@SendTo` **does not work** as you would wish. The handlers for `@PostMapping` (`org.springframework.servlet.*`) are different than those handling the `@MessageMapping` (`org.springframework.messaging.*`) and don't handle the `@SendTo` annotation in any special way.

You may want to use `SimpMessagingTemplate` to send the message explicitly: [How to call @SendTo from Normal Request Call i.e @RequestMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608584/how-to-call-sendto-from-normal-request-call-i-e-requestmapping)